# ldapadd - not working - ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ldap, openldap

How can i use ldapadd from terminal to add a ldapuseraccount?

I tried this code, it do not work:

```
ldapadd test
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W
```

- -x = simple binding
- -D = bind distinguished name
- -W = prompt for bind password

Then, enter your password.
Then, enter something like:

```
dn: cn=Test User,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
sn: User
```

Then, hit enter twice. It should add the user. Hit Control+D to quit the command.

That being said, I think there are better ways of adding users, such as using the `ldapadduser` command from the `ldapscripts` package, or - better yet - using phpLDAPadmin from package `phpldapadmin`.